# Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error 1 - Basic C++ with header files

Tags: c++, c, xcode

I am trying to create a Xcode project for the first time (I'm using C and C++, no Obj-C).

This is the structure of the project:

> project
>
> > main.cpp
>
> headers
>
> > a.h
> >     b.h
>
> sources
>
> > a.c
> >     b.c

**Sample content:**

a.h:

```
void some_fun();
```

b.h:

```
#include "a.h"
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "b.h"
int main(){
    some_fun();
}
```

In compile sources, main.cpp, a.c and b.c are included.
When I try to build this, I get one error for each invocation of `some_fun()` and then one more error.

**The errors are:**

> Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error
>   --"some_fun()" referenced from :
>   --_main in main.o

and

> Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error 
>   --Linker command failed with exit code 1

Is there anything I have missed in XCode configuration?
Is there a problem in using `a.h`'s function in `main.cpp` without explicitly including it?
Or is my structure fundamentally wrong due to some reason (I was able to build this via command line though) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic problem is that You've not marked the functions exposed in `a.c` and `b.c` as `C` code as opposed to `C++` code. `C++` uses a principle known as name mangling to expose functions in a form that identifies them for overloading, etc.

When you compiled the `a.c` file, it produced a `.o` file which doesn't contain any name mangling, because it's `C`.

Now when you use the code in a `C++` file (via the indirect `#include`), because you've not hinted to the `C++` compiler that the routine will be found in a `.o` file that contains `C` exposed routines, rather than `C++` exposed routines, the linker will not be able to make the connection.

The solution is simple, you have to use markers in the `.h` file to give these hits to the `C++` compiler. This is generally done by wrapping all the exposed symbols in a little bit of code that looks like:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void some_fun();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

you pretty much put the `extern "C"` piece at the start of the file, inside the [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) (you *do* have an include guard?). There's [another SO question] that explains how the `#ifdef __cplusplus` stuff works.